# SwiftUI for MacOS – dynamically changing the list highlight color

Tags: swift, swiftui

My app's main interface is a `NavigationSplitView` with a sidebar navigation and a main list navigation. SwiftUI automatically picks up the Assets folder's `AccentColor` to use for highlighting list items in both these lists.

For fun I've implemented a color picker so the user can set the app's accent color themselves – and using the modifier `.accentColor(tintColor)` on the main `ContentView` mostly works – buttons, toggles and toolbar items automatically get the new color. But I cannot find a way to make the lists use this new accent color for their selection color.

I would prefer not to use a solution such as `.listRowBackground(isSelected ? tintColor : Color.clear)` since it doesn't render quite the same on the Mac as the default selection background (with rounded corners, margins etc).

Is there a way to make this work?

Comment: There's no way to have a dynamic accent color / tint on list row highlight. Maybe it's a bug in which case you can submit a feedback. But for now, `.listRowBackground(isSelected ? tintColor : Color.clear)` seems to be the only working solution